# Blender to Unity3D texturing problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, modeling, texturing

I'm making models for a game, and to make them look a bit like holograms, I've given them transparent textures and wire-frames on the inside. For some reason when I export them into Unity3D they show up completely white with no wire-frame.

I have tried exporting as both an FBX and just as the .blend.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the actual texture in unity. Select it and then there is options for alpha is transparent or along the lines of that. It will have other options too. Sorry i dont have unity open in front of me but ive gotten around this issue by changing the options on the imported texture.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the materials of non working parts, maybe changing their shader to a transparent one?